# Insert a data sql to another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm currently working on my final college project using codeigniter.

It's a simple question.

I have tbl_members. It has "Student Id" as a primary key.

I want to input that "Student Id" into tbl_admins, of course it has "Student Id" column as well. I'm still new with codeigniter and sql.

I want to make a single-click-icon feature to make members become ==> admin with inserting his/her "student id" into tbl_admins

That feature 'add-admin' is ready on my view, shaped as font-awesome icon, inside a table column named 'promote admin'

Is there anyone can help with code?

Comment: SO is not for this purpose. Look for some tutorials. Try and if any problem, we're here.

Comment: Like I said, I want to add that "Student Id" from tbl_members into tbl_admins but I really don't know how? I'm poor with sql

Comment: It's not like I wasn't trying. I just give up. 3 members of my final project really didn't know anything, they can't help

Answer (score 0):

You should read carefully [CodeIgniter Doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) And for SQL, the instructions name is often sufficiently clear to intuitively understand it.

What you should do, if you want, is to retrieve the student_id in the database and save it in a variable (get_where()). Then, you insert it in the table admin (insert()).

I suggest you to try this. If you don't succeed, ask in comment.
In codeigniter, practicing is the key to learn (it worked for me.